# Is there a way to limit the queue size of a pedElevator block in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to simulate pedestrian movement in a building with an elevator but when I use the Anylogic `pedElevator` block the pedestrians pile up in front of the elevator door. The agents have entered the elevator block and can be counted via `elevatorQueueSize()` but I cannot find how to limit the capacity of this integrated queue.

Can anyone help how to limit the number of waiting pedestrians in a `pedElevator` block?

Answer (score 0):

Put a normal `Queue` block from the process modelling library in front of your block and limit it there.

(You can mix and match blocks from the ped library and the process flow library)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but the pedestrians just pass through the queue block and accumulate in front of the elevator doors (blocking it). It seems because the pedElevator block also contains an integrated unlimited queue the preceding queue can immediately pass the pedestrians.

Comment: True, this is how Queues behave. You need to manage this yourself as with any other flow chart :) Use a Hold block, or a RestrictedArea setup. (Queue blocks do not cause queues, they manage them :) ) -> This is what I meant by "limit it there"